# Ubuntu 18.10 Ethernet LAN doesn't connect

Tags: ethernet, 18.10, lan

My LAN connection doesn't connect. I got a new router. Since that Ubuntu won't connect. Any ideas? On Windows 10 the LAN connection works. IPv6 seems to work. Just not IPv4.

Edit: It's a Smart 3 from the German Telekom. Everything worked with the old router. I can't attach pic so have uploaded it to my next loud. Link: [pic of screen](https://c.nextgamers.eu/index.php/s/2zfWATp8rJRYTpi)
I also tried rebooting and after a reinstall I still have the same problem. Also I think the problem is caused by a dhcp violation.

Edit #2: It's connected by ethernet cable. It works under Windows. Everything is connected correctly. There is nothing in the blocked list in the routers admin interface. I can't even access the LAN over IPv4. So the problem is acquiring a LAN IPv4 over DHCP.

Edit #3: The network card PC is connected to the routers LAN using an ethernet LAN cable. The router is connected using a normal telephone cable to the outside. It's an IP telephony router. Well all LEDs are white (no problem). My laptop (wlan) can access the internet and acquire an IPv4 for LAN. ifconfig is not installed by default and I can't access the internet so I can't give you the output of the command. All I can say is, IPv6 works, IPv4 does not.

Edit #4: I can't send you the tab screenshots. Though everything is default and automatic. I can't ping 8.8.8.8 - network unreachable. Here screenshot of the commands: [2nd screenshot](https://c.nextgamers.eu/index.php/s/QFQG3xCHgdaNYee)

Edit #5: Here the screenshot. I use a mobile phone app to talk here. Can't exchange clipboard between the devices. [3rd screenshot](https://c.nextgamers.eu/index.php/s/wmJmKMWo4ccc23E) I've read somewhere that it's trying to get an IP but it violates some protocol. Has to do with nxdomain or something.

Edit: The debug log wasn't there. Here the screenshot from Windows. [Screenshot](https://c.nextgamers.eu/index.php/s/Ej9KaeBRZ444Y2t)

Comment: And just for fun, boot into Windows, open a command terminal, and type `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` (I don't remember which on Windows), and see if you're getting an IPv4 address there, or just an IPv6 address.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89945/discussion-on-question-by-uwe-pfeifer-ubuntu-18-10-ethernet-lan-doesnt-connect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, we're able to get a proper IPv4 and IPv6 address.

In Ubuntu, dhcp4 is timing out, but we're able to get a IPv6 address. All of the network settings in Ubuntu look fine. We're trying to see if a manual IP will temporarily work in Ubuntu. (set IPv4 to manual, with IP 192.168.2.105/24, gateway 192.168.2.1, DNS 8.8.8.8).

A new router was installed, and the problems began then. I suspect that the router isn't supplying a complete response to dhcp, specifically in regards to domain, or domainname.

Contact your ISP for further router troubleshooting.

Comment: @UwePfeifer Please let me know the results. If you're able to get it going with your ISP, please remember to come back here and accept my answer. Did the manual settings work? Thanks!

Comment: I contacted my isp per email. Will take a day or two. Will report back then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @UwePfeifer did the manual settings work for you? Is the Internet up now?

Comment: No response yet.

Comment: @UwePfeifer oh, you misunderstood my question... it was did the manual settings that I gave you work to get you on the Internet, whilst you're waiting for a response from your ISP?

Comment: oh yes. I misunderstood that. I will test it the day after tomorrow. Have to go to bed now and busy tomorrow. Sorry.

Comment: Hey. I tried the manual settings and it says temporary failure in name resolution when trying to ping.

Comment: I set 8.8.8.8 as DNS. It works now. Can ping over IPV4. Great!

Comment: @UwePfeifer great! Until your ISP resolves the problem, or replaces the router/modem, at least you can work. What was the reason for the original swap?

Comment: The reason for the swap was access to FON Hotspots. Those are public wlan hotspots private and from businesses all over the world. I only get access to those if I provide a hotspot myself. My old router didn't support it. I will accept your answer now.